# Add element inside main menu block, but outside navigation

Tags: 7, theming, routes, blocks

I need to add an element *somewhere* within, or directly before/after, the main menu block. For example, the generated HTML should be something like this:

```
<div id="main-navigation">
  <div class="block block-system" id="block-system-main-menu">
    <div class="block-inner clearfix">
      <div class="content clearfix">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="first expanded">
            <a href="">About</a>
            <ul class="menu">
              <li class="first leaf">
                <a href="">General Info</a>
              </li>
              <li class="leaf"><a href="">Video</a></li>
                <!-- ... other menu items -->
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul> <!-- this ends the top level main ul.menu -->
        <!-- a div added here would be ok -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- or a div added here would be ok -->
```

I am currently trying [`hook_block_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) and have tried multiple variations of something like this:

```
function theme_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if ($block->delta == 'main-menu'
    && $block->region == 'menu') {
    $data['content'][] = array(
      '#markup' => '<div class="."><a href="#top">Close Mobile Menu</a></div>'
    );
  }
}
```

which is the closest I have come.  This adds the div within `ul.menu` (top level) after the last `li` element; that won't work.

I can't seem to find a theming function for the menu as a whole, just `theme_menu_links()`.  I see the theme wrapper `menu_tree__main_menu` within `$data` in `hook_block_view_alter()`, but I don't see a file or function that resembles that.

I'm aware that there may be a much better solution that I'm just not thinking of, so I'll state the final goal:

1. Absolute positioned menu. (I can work with `#main-navigation` being absolute and the element coming after it **or** with `ul.menu` being positioned, and the element coming after it.)
2. A link that follows the menu in markup, but is outside of the absolute positioned menu, so that I can position relative to window, not the `ul`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish all your goals, you need to implement these three functions:

- [hook_preprocess_block()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7)
- [theme_menu_tree()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7)
- [theme_menu_link()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7)

Create one template file for the block with your menu.

#### template.php

```
/**
 * Implements hook__preprocess_block().
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables, $hook) {
  // allow to use block templates depend on delta
  // example: delta = main-menu ; template file: block--main-menu.tpl.php
 if ($variables['block']->delta == 'main-menu') {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__' . str_replace('-', '_', $variables['block']->delta);
 } 
}

/**
 * Main menu
 * Implements theme__menu_tree().
 */
function YOURTHEME_menu_tree__main_menu($variables) {
    global $level;
    $div = ($level == 1) ? '<div> ... some div next to the main ul ... </div>' : '';
    $ul = '<ul class="menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>' . $div;
    return $ul;
}

/**
 * Main menu
 * Implements theme__menu_link().
 */
function YOURTHEME_menu_link__main_menu($variables) {

  $element = $variables['element'];
  $title = $element['#title'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  // global menu level variable. 
  // within theme_menu_tree() at first level has always value = 1
  // but not here, that's why $depth will have to be defined separately
  global $level;
  $level = $element['#original_link']['depth'];

  // if you will need $depth, it must be defined separately
  // $depth = $element['#original_link']['depth']; 

  // submenu
  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  // link output
  $output = l($title, $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

  // if link class is active, make li class as active too
  if(strpos($output,"active")>0){
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = "active";
  }

  $attr = drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']);
  return  '<li' . $attr . '>' . $output .$sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

#### block--main-menu.tpl.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * theme's implementation to display a block with the main menu.
 */     
?>
<div id="main-navigation">
  <div class="block block-system" id="block-system-main-menu">
    <div class="block-inner clearfix">
      <div class="content clearfix">
        <?php print $content; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- or a div added here would be ok -->
<div> ... some div next to the main navigation div ... </div>
```

#### Results

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

What about page.tpl.php? It will allow you the add the extra markup before / after the menu. 
I think that theme_preprocess_page may also do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'd prefer to keep it in the block if possible though. I think my issue is I don't yet understand renderable arrays.